# Why does CSS Grid layout add extra gaps between cells?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Can’t figure out why CSS grid layout adds an unwanted extra space to content around the vertical cells, though margin and padding are zeroed out:

[image: images positioned with CSS grid]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 13fr 11fr 4fr 20fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 12fr;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid figure {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid figure img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.grid .gi13x12 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}

.grid .gi11x6.one {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}

.grid .gi11x6.two {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 7;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}

.grid .gi4x4.one {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}

.grid .gi4x4.two {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 9;
}

.grid .gi4x4.three {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 9;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}

.grid .gi20x12 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <figure class="gi13x12">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/130x123">
  </figure>
  <figure class="gi11x6 one">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/110x60">
  </figure>
  <figure class="gi11x6 two">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/110x60">
  </figure>
  <figure class="gi4x4 one">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
  </figure>
  <figure class="gi4x4 two">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
  </figure>
  <figure class="gi4x4 three">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
  </figure>
  <figure class="gi20x12">
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x120">
  </figure>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adanchenkov/dy77hk9k/

Comment: That space has nothing to do with CSS Grid, margin or padding, it comes from the fact that an `img` is an inline element, which like characters has a white space, for descenders, below the baseline.

Comment: @LGSon, I don't believe descenders are the problem in this case.

Comment: @Michael_B The question has been updated after I answered. If you check how the code within the question renders, you'll see why I both commented and answered saying just that. The fiddle, which the added screen dump shows, renders a different result. Still, my answer does solve both those issues, though yours does is in a more correct way. so +1 from me :)

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for the comment, I added a note in my answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The vertical gaps are caused by the images not filling the vertical space in the grid items.

The problem is made worse with `align-items: center` on the container, which removes the `align-items: stretch` default.

Essentially, there are no gaps between grid items. They form a clean, neatly-arranged grid. But because the images are smaller than the items that contain them, and the items are then centered vertically with `align-items`, there are lots of gaps.

Here's a more detailed explanation, using Firefox's grid overlay tool for illustration:

(1) This is your grid ***when `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` are 0***:

[image]

The red lines represent the grid items. The images are the content of the grid items. The dotted lines represent the grid lines.

---

(2) There is no problem ***when `grid-column-gap` is 10px***:

[image]

---

(3) But look what happens ***when `grid-row-gap` is 10px***:

[image]

The grid items (red lines) neatly wrap their content (the images). This happens only because the container is set to `align-items: center`.

---

(4) Now let's removes `align-items: center` (which restores the default `stretch` value) and keep `grid-column-gap: 10px` and `grid-row-gap: 10px`:

[image]

As you can see, the grid items (having red borders and yellow backgrounds) now expand full height. But the images, being smaller than the items, leave gaps.

---

(5) Here's the grid from (4) above without the indicators.

**`align-items: stretch`**

[image]

**`align-items: center`** (same layout as in the question)

[image]

---

(6) So the key is to get the images to fill the grid items.

One simple solution is to apply `display: flex` to the grid items, which will automatically assign `align-items: stretch` to the images, causing them to take full height.

And then, depending on how you want the images to look, you can use `object-fit` to manage their appearance.

Add this to your code:

```
.grid figure {
   display: flex;
}

.grid figure img {
   object-fit: cover; /* also try `contain` and `fill` */
}
```

With the adjustments above, the grid renders like this:

[image]

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dy77hk9k/3/)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 13fr 11fr 4fr 20fr;
  grid-auto-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /* align-items: center; */
}
.grid figure {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex; /* new */
}
.grid figure img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover; /* new */
}
.grid .gi13x12 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
.grid .gi11x6.one {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}
.grid .gi11x6.two {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 7;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
.grid .gi4x4.one {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
.grid .gi4x4.two {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 9;
}
.grid .gi4x4.three {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 9;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
.grid .gi20x12 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <figure class="gi13x12">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/130x123">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi11x6 one">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/110x60">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi11x6 two">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/110x60">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi4x4 one">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi4x4 two">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi4x4 three">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi20x12">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x120">
 </figure>
</div>
```

---

**Cool grid overlay feature in Firefox**

In Firefox dev tools, when you inspect the grid container, there is a tiny grid icon in the CSS declaration. On click it displays an outline of your grid on the page.

[image]

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts

Answer (score 5):

*Note, this answer where posted prior to the latest update, and as such, answer the initial code sample (the one within the question) differently. The edited version of the question is brilliantly answered by Michael.*

First, the inner space has nothing to do with CSS Grid, margin or padding, it comes from the fact that an `img` is an inline element, which like characters has a white space, for descenders, below the baseline.

One solution for that is to add `display: block` to the `.grid figure img` rule.

```
.grid figure img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

Second, the outer space is caused by the `grid-auto-rows`, so remove that from the `.grid` rule.

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 13fr 11fr 4fr 20fr;
  /*grid-auto-rows: 12fr;                      remove this  */
  grid-gap: 3px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 13fr 11fr 4fr 20fr;
  /*grid-auto-rows: 12fr;                      removed  */
  grid-gap: 3px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.grid figure {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.grid figure img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.grid .gi13x12 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
.grid .gi11x6.one {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}
.grid .gi11x6.two {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 7;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
.grid .gi4x4.one {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
.grid .gi4x4.two {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 5;
  grid-row-end: 9;
}
.grid .gi4x4.three {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 9;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
.grid .gi20x12 {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 13;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <figure class="gi13x12">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/130x123">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi11x6 one">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/110x60">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi11x6 two">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/110x60">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi4x4 one">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi4x4 two">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi4x4 three">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/40x39">
 </figure>
 <figure class="gi20x12">
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x120">
 </figure>
</div>
```

---

Regarding your Fiddle sample (and added screen dump), where neither matching the inner code sample, and after the above adjustments, there is still a small inner space, which is caused by the fact that the sum of the smaller elements height does not match the highest one, nor does its images, as the highest image is 123px, but smaller images are 120px (2*60) and 117px (3*39).

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for editing fiddle link. It does match the edited question and with gap value of 3 px the heights of all 4 columns should be equal: 123px = 60px*2+3px = 39px*3+3px*2 = 123px. The question still remains: What causes gap value to be greater than set 3px between vertically stacked elements in columns 2 and 3?

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov Updated my answer, and it is caused by `grid-auto-rows` ... https://jsfiddle.net/dy77hk9k/1/

Comment: grid-auto-rows may seem redundant, but it defines 12 rows, which are then used for grid-row-start and grid-row-end of individual items. Even then I don't see how smaller images with gap take bigger height?

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov As you don't have any elements outside the range of the defined grid, which is what `grid-auto-rows` are for, how do you plan to position rows (via `grid-template-rows`) that should be out of the range?

Comment: you are right. `grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);` should have been included. it does not change the spacing issue.

Comment: Thanks for   align-items: flex-start;

Answer (score -1):

to Remove Gap after cell place "    grid-gap: 0px;" to .grid css class

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the space inside the figure by making the image to float.

```
.grid figure img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
```

Please find the update code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1hjrhupy/2/).

Comment: floating (outside of being a strange beast in grid layout) didn't work with non-zero grid-gap. I do want to keep the grid-gap of 3px (which should work as per spec).