# Unexpected empty space inside rows in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The difference with this (partially duplicate) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616289/why-does-css-grid-layout-add-extra-gaps-between-cells) is that I don't use align-items: center, I use start. If I use display: flex on grid-item and object-fit: contain/cover/fill on image it doesn't solve the problem.

My task is to create this grid:

[image: grid layout].

In order to do it I use css grid and grid-template-areas.

In result, I have unexpected empty space inside some rows. Are there some rules that can deal with it? Or maybe html structure should be fixed?

[image: result]

```css
.masttech-gallery__list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "pic1 pic2 pic2 pic3"
    "pic1 pic2 pic2 pic6"
    "pic4 pic2 pic2 pic6"
    "pic4 pic5 pic5 pic6"
    "pic7 pic5 pic5 pic6";
  align-items: start;
  list-style: none;
}

.masttech-gallery__item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<article class="masttech-gallery js-gallery js-block">
  <ul class="masttech-gallery__list">
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic1; margin-left: calc(-1 * 100% - 40px);">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x2292">
    </li>
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic2;">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x3564">
    </li>
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic3; margin-right: calc(-1 * 100% - 40px);">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x2084">
    </li>
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic4; margin-left: calc(-1 * 100% - 40px);">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1750">
    </li>
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic5;">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x2188">
    </li>
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic6; margin-right: calc(-1 * 100% - 40px);">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x2526">
    </li>
    <li class="masttech-gallery__item" style="grid-area: pic7; margin-left: calc(-1 * 100% - 40px);">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1064">
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

**The solution.**

Just fix grid-template-rows to min-content min-content min-content 1fr 4fr.

Comment: it's not a space between rows but a space inside the row, simply because the image is small

Comment: @TemaniAfif okay, but then how to deal with this space?

Comment: I solved the problem, just to fix grid-template-rows to min-content min-content min-content 1fr 4fr.